# Do BNO(Business Network Operator) have a Notary?

Tags: blockchain, corda, notary

According to the Corda docs for eg: While on-boarding a node to Business network,if we want to approve a pending membership that has passed through the review and approval checks, BNO would approve it.So the procedure is,BNO does KYC checks,creates a transaction which changes membership status to ACTIVE and notarise the transaction,then send to the pending member .So in this procedure,BNO is using a notary.So which notary is it using?Do BNO have a separate notary or will go for any available notary in the network?

Answer (score 1):

A BNO Node could be set up to host certain network services, in that case he would use the same notaries as is used by the participants of the business network. However, a BNO node doesn't generally participate in business transactions.

Refer here for more details:
https://solutions.corda.net/business-networks/business-network-operator-node.html

Comment: Thanks!!So can we customise the BNO's Flow?And also while we on-board a new node,it is said to do KYC process.Are they doing something?